# CodingBat > Warmup-1 > parrot_trouble

Tags: python, function, boolean

This is my first question as a programmer, I am teaching myself Python and am hoping you can help me figure out why my answer to this problem is wrong.

I understand that the solution is simpler and probably syntactically more correct but I am wondering why my code didn't work at all.

**The problem I'm working on:**

Link:
https://codingbat.com/prob/p166884

Problem Pasted Here:
We have a loud talking parrot. The "hour" parameter is the current hour time in the range 0..23. We are in trouble if the parrot is talking and the hour is before 7 or after 20. Return True if we are in trouble.

parrot_trouble(True, 6) → True
parrot_trouble(True, 7) → False
parrot_trouble(False, 6) → False

**My answer:**

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
        if talking == True and hour < 7 == True or hour > 20 == True:
            return(True)
```

**Result:**

```
Expected    Run     
parrot_trouble(True, 6) → True  None    X   
parrot_trouble(True, 7) → False None    X   
parrot_trouble(False, 6) → False    None    X   
parrot_trouble(True, 21) → True None    X   
parrot_trouble(False, 21) → False   None    X   
parrot_trouble(False, 20) → False   None    X   
parrot_trouble(True, 23) → True None    X   
parrot_trouble(False, 23) → False   None    X   
parrot_trouble(True, 20) → False    None    X   
parrot_trouble(False, 12) → False   None    X
```

**The solution:**

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
  return (talking and (hour < 7 or hour > 20))
      Need extra parenthesis around the or clause
      since and binds more tightly than or.
      and is like arithmetic *, or is like arithmetic +
```

I tried parenthesis around the hour boolean expressions but that didn't work either:

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
        if talking == True and (hour < 7 == True or hour > 20 == True):
            return(True)
```

I'm not sure where my thinking went wrong. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is a keyword, not a function. Try `return True` instead of `return(True)`.

This is because the parentheses symbolize executing a function, so it would mean you are calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
        if talking == True and (hour<7 or hour>20):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Please give some more details about why this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is your syntax with this statement

```
(hour < 7 == True or hour > 20 == True)
```

You need not put the '== true' when you have already made the statement hour < 7.

simply change it to

```
(hour < 7 or hour > 20)
```